# bitcoind still running after 'bitcoin-cli stop'

Tags: bitcoind

I'm running Debian 11, all updates installed. 12gb RAM, massive internal SSD for storage.

`$ /usr/local/bin/bitcoin-25.0/bin/bitcoin-cli stop` has worked well shutting down bitcoind on my computer until today, when it seems to have hanged half way through the usual process.

`$ tail .bitcoin/debug.log` shows:

```
2023-11-27T13:51:11Z tor: Thread interrupt
2023-11-27T13:51:11Z torcontrol thread exit
2023-11-27T13:51:11Z Shutdown: In progress...
2023-11-27T13:51:11Z addcon thread exit
2023-11-27T13:51:11Z opencon thread exit
2023-11-27T13:51:11Z net thread exit
2023-11-27T13:51:11Z msghand thread exit
2023-11-27T14:20:38Z Potential stale tip [snipped]
2023-11-27T14:31:08Z Potential stale tip [snipped]
2023-11-27T14:41:38Z Potential stale tip [snipped]
```

... `$ ps ax | fgrep bitcoind` shows:

```
  1399 ?        SLl  171:06 /usr/local/bin/bitcoin-25.0/bin/bitcoind
  10818 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep -F bitcoind
```

... and `$ top` reveals:

```
 1399 [username] 20 0 4218920 1.0g 184480 S 0.3 8.5 171:06.03 b-shutoff
```

... so only 0.3% CPU used; mostly, b-shutoff doesn't show up at all in `$ top`'s output, so b-shutoff is definitely not working hard.

Contents of .bitcoin/ are:

```
    banlist.json
    bitcoin.conf
    bitcoind.pid
    blocks
    chainstate
    database
    db.log
    debug.log
    fee_estimates.dat
    mempool.dat
    peers.dat
    settings.json
```

... so no "lock" file visible there.

So, did I do anything unusual before I entered `bitcoin-cli stop`? Yes, two things I don't usually do:

1. Some hours before the attempted stop, I ran `rescan`, which seems to have worked perfectly well.
2. I was running bisq when I entered `bitcoin-cli stop`. I have now closed bisq ("A bit late now!" you might say...) but the b-shutoff is still hung.

Would be grateful for any suggestions, or questions you might have that could help me out closing the daemon gracefully.

**Edit**, some hours later. Needed to press on, tried to quit the bitcoind/b-shutoff PID from `$ top` command, but that didn't work so I rebooted the machine. Back up now, quick look around in the .bitcoin dir and oh, looky here--the lock file was a hidden file, no wonder I didn't see it earlier! Doh. So, `$ rm` the .lock file, and now bitcoind is running fine again, nothing untoward to report.

**Further edit**, I tried to give a "b-shutoff" tag to this post, but no such tag exists, and I see "Creating the new tag 'b-shutoff' requires at least 150 reputation." I think it would be a useful tag, so if I may suggest it, if anybody with 150 reputation agrees, please make one :)

Comment: It's possible to run multiple `bitcoind` instances on a single machine. The command `bitcoind --testnet` will run `bitcoind` on `testnet`.

To stop your testnet `bitcoind` you should run `bitcoind --testnet stop`.

Is it possible you have a `bitcoind` instance running on another `bitcoindir`